# Custom getFilter()

Tags: android, filtering, android-arrayadapter

I have scoured the internet looking for answers and can't seem to find why my custom getFilter() doesn't work. Here is the code.

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() 
{
    return new Filter()
    {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) 
        {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if(charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0)
            {
                results.values = original_list;
                results.count = original_list.length;
            }else
            {
                List<String> filteredResults = new ArrayList<String>();

                for(int i = 0; i < original_list.length; i++)
                {
                    if(original_list[i].toString().toLowerCase().contains(charSequence))
                    {
                        filteredResults.add(original_list[i]);
                    }
                }

                String[] list = new String[filteredResults.size()];

                for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
                {
                    list[i] = filteredResults.get(i);
                }

                results.count = list.length;
                results.values = list;
            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults filteredResults)
        {
            filtered_list = (String[])filteredResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        };
    }
}
```

I'm at wits end trying to figure out why when I use a string array with the stock ArrayAdapter filtering works perfect, but with my custom filter it crashes every time I type in my EditText

Comment: if it crashes your logcat shows where it does

Comment: withour logcat, we cant helps you buddy.

Comment: Well how do i get logcat to start telling me things then

Comment: so this is why i am trying to avoid ArrayAdapter when possible, i am using [Simple]CursorAdapter instead